# An easier way to get average of a table with some conditions in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get the average of all 6 quizzes for each male student.
Here is part of the code that I've tried:

```
a<-subset(mydf,Sex=="M")
b<-a[4:9]
b
sum(b[1:6])
```

My logic is to get a table only contains male students with each of their 6 quizzes, then sum the table and divide by the number of male student. But I think there should be an easier way to do this.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(Section=c(rep('A',9)),
                 Degree=c(rep('MBA',4),'MS','MBA','MBA','MS','MBA'),
                 Sex=c(rep('M',5),'F','M','M','F'),
                 Quiz1=c(0,10,2,2,8,6,6,2,3),
                 Quiz2=c(0,1,4,4,1,5,0,3,9),
                 Quiz3=c(6,5,6,6,4,2,7,9,3),
                 Quiz4=c(5,4,5,5,10,5,7,7,3),
                 Quiz5=c(7,3,6,3,10,7,6,10,5),
                 Quiz6=c(3,8,6,6,5,8,10,10,5))
```

Comment: Please include data as plain text, not images. What do you mean by "average of all 6 quizzes?" Do you want 6 averages: for quiz 1, quiz 2...up to quiz 6? Or one average of the scores from all 6 quizzes combined?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
data.frame(df[which(df$Sex=='M'),],QuizMeans=rowMeans(df[which(df$Sex=='M'),c(4:9)]))
```

Note: "c(4:9)" in the code above is takes the row average for quiz columns 4-9.
    So we're calculating quiz scores for each individual this way.

Output:

```
  Section Degree Sex Quiz1 Quiz2 Quiz3 Quiz4 Quiz5 Quiz6 QuizMeans
1       A    MBA   M     0     0     6     5     7     3  3.500000
2       A    MBA   M    10     1     5     4     3     8  5.166667
3       A    MBA   M     2     4     6     5     6     6  4.833333
4       A    MBA   M     2     4     6     5     3     6  4.333333
5       A     MS   M     8     1     4    10    10     5  6.333333
7       A    MBA   M     6     0     7     7     6    10  6.000000
8       A     MS   M     2     3     9     7    10    10  6.833333
```

Then if you wanted to take the mean of their means (i.e. the grand mean), you could store the above as something like "df", then use mean() to calculate the mean of the column QuizMeans, like this:

```
df <- data.frame(df[which(df$Sex=='M'),],QuizMeans=rowMeans(df[which(df$Sex=='M'),c(4:9)]))
mean(df$QuizMeans)
[1] 5.285714
```

If there are missing values in your data, you'll need to add na.rm=TRUE to either the mean() or rowMeans() function, like this:

```
mean(df$QuizMeans, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 5.285714
```

Comment: @Lin - If your question has been answered, please select a solution to let the community know and to help others with similar questions find their answers even faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following without specifying column positions

```
ans <- sum(df[df$Sex=="M", grepl("Quiz",names(df))])/sum(df$Sex=="M")
# 31.71429
```

If you know the column positions

```
ans <- sum(df[df$Sex=="M", 4:9])/sum(df$Sex=="M")
# 31.71429
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(Section=c(rep('A',9)),
                 Degree=c(rep('MBA',4),'MS','MBA','MBA','MS','MBA'),
                 Sex=c(rep('M',5),'F','M','M','F'),
                 Quiz1=c(0,10,2,2,8,6,6,2,3),
                 Quiz2=c(0,1,4,4,1,5,0,3,9),
                 Quiz3=c(6,5,6,6,4,2,7,9,3),
                 Quiz4=c(5,4,5,5,10,5,7,7,3),
                 Quiz5=c(7,3,6,3,10,7,6,10,5),
                 Quiz6=c(3,8,6,6,5,8,10,10,5))
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use `dplyr`.**

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% filter(Sex == "Male") %>% 
  summarise(avg_q6 = mean(Quiz6))
```